# How do I import a csv file with data colum in oracle 10g

Tags: sql-loader

I have the folowing files

1. arv.csv
2. arv.ctl

in my D:\ToBeImportedFiles

The contents of arv.csv are

```
101,2010,12/12/2012
102,2012,15/4/2015
```

The contents of arv.ctl are

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'D:\ToBeImportedFiles\arv.csv' 
REPLACE 
INTO TABLE trn622094.sample4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(IDE INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
 YEAR INTEGER EXTERNAL,
         DATEOFJOINING   
)
```

The table in my schema is:

```
IDE                                                NUMBER
YEAR                                               NUMBER
DATEOFJOINING                                      DATE
```

When I type the following in my cmd: 
    SQLLDR  [myconnectionstring]  control=D:\ToBeImportedFiles\arv.ctl

I got my two records in .bad file. Why is it so? Can anybody explain me please. What is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a log file somewhere with better explanation with the name "arv.log".

In my past case, the issue could be solved by the following:

```
 , DATEOFJOINING DATE "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried with your suggestion and it work, thanks a lot.